# How does Android memory allocation work with ImageView?

Tags: android, memory-management

I'm loading approximately 20 pictures of size 50-70K from server, then display them in a `ListView`. Initially I stored the data as `Bitmap` which causes memory running out quickly. Then I decided to compress all these bitmap files and store in Content provider `Media`. So in my adapter, the user data only contains the `Uri` to the image file.

However it didn't fix the problem at all, it run a bit longer, but still crashed after loading about 10 pictures or so. Here is the error log from the compiler.
`1048576-byte external allocation too large for this process`
`VM won't let us allocate 1048576 bytes`

I even clean up each `bitmap` data after setting it to my `ImageView`, plus delete the all the image files which are stored in my `sdcard`

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // clean up
        for (User user : userList) {
            getContentResolver().delete(user.getImageUri(), null, null);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private Uri constructUriFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
        values.put(Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        try {
            OutputStream outStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outStream);
            outStream.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception while writing image", e);
        }
        bitmap.recycle();
        return uri;
    }
```

Now I ran out of idea, I really don't know what could go wrong in this case. I wonder if anyone has experienced this issue could shed me some lights?

Since the code is quite long, I only extract the main functions: 
Here is my `User class` data:

```
public class FriendFeed {
    // required parameters
    private final int activityId; // in case we want to handle the detail of
                                    // this activity
    private final int friendId;
    private final String friendName;
    private final Challenge.Type challengeType;
    private final String activityTime;
    private final String placeName;

    // optional parameter
    private String challengeName;
    private String challengeDescription;
    private Uri activitySnapPictureUri = null;
    private Uri friendPictureUri = null;
    private String activityComment;
```

And here is my main function:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void...voids) {
            JSONArray array = JsonHelper.getJsonArrayFromUrlWithData(GET_FRIEND_FEED_URL, datas);
            if (array != null) { 
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) { 
                        Uri snapPictureUri = null;
                        Uri userPictureUri = null;

                        if (Challenge.returnType(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("challenges_tbl_type")) == Challenge.Type.SNAP_PICTURE) {
                            snapPictureUri = constructUriFromBitmap(ImageHelper.downloadImage(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("activity_tbl_snap_picture_url")));
                        }

                        if(ImageHelper.downloadImage(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("users_tbl_user_image_url")) != null) {
                            userPictureUri = constructUriFromBitmap(ImageHelper.downloadImage(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("users_tbl_user_image_url")));
                        }

                        publishProgress(
                            new FriendFeed.Builder(
                                    // required parameters
                                    array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("activity_tbl_id"),
                                    array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("friends_tbl_friend_id"),
                                    array.getJSONObject(i).getString("users_tbl_username"),
                                    Challenge.returnType(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("challenges_tbl_type")),
                                    array.getJSONObject(i).getString("activity_tbl_created"),
                                    array.getJSONObject(i).getString("spots_tbl_name"))
                                        // optional parameters
                                        .challengeName(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("challenges_tbl_name"))
                                        .challengeDescription(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("challenges_tbl_description"))
                                        .activitySnapPictureUri(snapPictureUri)
                                        .friendPictureUri(userPictureUri)
                                        .activityComment(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("activity_tbl_comment"))
                                            .build());
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG + "GetFriendFeedTask.doInBackGround(Void ...voids) : ", "JSON error parsing data" + e.toString());
                }
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android enforces a per-process memory allocation limit of 24MB so you can't allocate more than that. However, 20 pics of 70K each should amount to 1.4MB only... so my guesses:

1. Maybe you're allocating Bitmaps in other parts of your app, so that there's less than 1.4MB available for your bitmaps on this ListView.
2. Memory leak somewhere
3. If you determine that you really need all the bitmaps you're using, are you sure you need the bitmaps to be this large or have this much resolution? Reducing them can help.

If all else fails and you do need lots of bitmaps in memory, you can always use OpenGL textures.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Most of my other activities are still loading `Bitmap`. I will change them later following the above method if it really works out. But even if I haven't changed others, I only run this activity, how do other activities got involved though?

Comment: @BrunoOliveira Maybe you had images on activity A then you go to activity B and there are more images there, now activity A is not destroyed, its just running in the background of activity B, this causes memory allocation problems